Alternative to the Frutiger family
I'm looking for an alternative to the Frutiger font family that is available by default on Windows and/or macOS. I would greatly appreciate any recommendations.

You're asking for an alternative to Frutiger, but one of the system fonts? Have you checked the fonts in your own computer?? What's special about Frutiger that you need in an alternative font, can you [edit] your question to add more details?

take your pick

If you're just looking for a Frutiger look-alike, humanist sans serif font that is already available on Windows / Mac you could use Verdana. It's a web safe font so it's available almost everywhere.
